# Load an activitiy based on the mobile´s date; Eclipse app

Tags: java, android, date

I would like to know if it is possible to load an activity based on the mobile´s date.

Ex. On 01 of January it loads Activity1, 
    on 02 of January it loads Activity2, 
    and so on.

(Edit)

HI.

I just started to learn java and android, i am still at a very low level programming.
I have managed to create a very simple app with various activities.

In this app, I would like to have an Activity in which other Activities are loaded automaticaly depending on the the day of the year.

I tried to do this but as I am just a beginner, I would need examples based the names of my activities (Main, One and two) and also for day 1 and 2 of Frebruary. So that I can understand better.

As I understood 1 of February would mean"32" and 2 of February would mean"33"

So if i have 3 Activities:

MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml, OneActivity.java, activity_one.xml and TwoActivity.java, activity_two.xml

When starting MainActivity, i would like it to load OneActivity if its is day 1 of February 2015 or load TwoActivity if its is day 2 of February 2015.

Comment: Did you try doing that? I don't see any reason of it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do this. To get the date, just use the Calendar API, like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

This will get you the day of the year. So Jan 1 will be `1`, Feb 1 will be `32`, and so on.

Then have an `array` of `String`s that holds the class you want to open each day.

```
String[] className = {"empty because the first day is 1", "nameofClass1","nameofClass2", ... , "nameofClass365"};
```

Then you'll just have a Splashscreen sort of activity that will call an intent to that class.

```
Class<?> c = null;
if(StringClassname != null) {
    try {
        c = Class.forName(className[dayOfYear]);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: why an array of `String` instead of an array of `Class`?

Comment: I´m just a beginner, could you place the full code of the page as an example? I´m getting an error at"if(StringClassname != null) {".Where do I place the array of string? Where/how do I place the name of the Actovity I want to load?

Comment: I finally did it! Thank you so much. For me it wasn´t working because i hadn´t put the package plus activity name of the classes. Ex:    {"", "com.mares.marenostrum.MainActivity","nameofClass365"};

Answer (score 0):

you want to know if its possible?

**YES**

you did not add how, did you?

well for how you could use [compareTo(Date anotherDate)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) .